# How can i create a clickable image without html involved?

Tags: photoshop, user-experience

I'm trying to create an image (*.png, *.jpg, etc.) with some clickable area (could be a text), so if user will click on the clickable area it will do some action, please note that i don't want to use any HTML/CSS structure and the main idea is to create an image that is already ave clickable area.

**For example**:

Lets say i have an image with text inside the behind it there is an http://somewhere.com. now, when user will click on it will navigate him to the hidden http address but remember that the image was created with no HTML/CSS tags or structure.

Thanks for all the expert 
in advanced (-:

Comment: I'm confused - you want to do this outside a browser, or what?

Comment: I do not understand your "lets say..." sentence. How does the user see that image? With a browser on a webpage? Why souldnt there be any html/css involved?

Comment: in the linked web page, what clickable image are your referring ?

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstood, think of an image with text (clickable text) so if i will upload it to whatsapp person that will press the text will be navigate for example to some web page opened with the device browser

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like an image file, which an clickable area for me. This is not possible without some code, so if you don't want to do it with html or css, you can use a javascript, but this is even more complicated.